# cannot delete wwwroot on azure

Tags: node.js, azure, kudu

I am trying to run an NodeJs app on Azure app services for Linux. After a failed deployment I would like to delete the wwwroot folder and start from scratch, but I am not able to delete it.
I have tried using ssh, bash, ftp and the Kudu REST API, but every time the result is the same.

This is the response from the DELETE call:

**{"Message":"Cannot delete directory. It is either not empty or access is not allowed."}**

Looks like there's an hidden **.bin** folder inside **/node_modules** that is blocking the delete operation.

[image]

Any hint?

Comment: Please mention that its Azure app service for Linux (I was puzzled for a while until I saw Kudu mentioned), anyways an ideal way to make a new build is to do a fresh git push and delete the old code before that git commit. The folder rights don't belong to a single host in this case. Delete the contents if you will but always try to do any such stuff using the git deployments

Comment: problem is that I cannot delete the files, I get an access denied error

Comment: Try stopping the Web App first (Portal or CLI). Then go to Kudu and wipe out `node_modules`.

Comment: did that already, was the first thing :(

Comment: Try rename (or move) to another file name see if it unblocks you.   The file might be in weird state.

Comment: tried with FTP:

Status:       Renaming '/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/mime' to '/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/mimee'
Command: RNFR mime
Response:  550 Access is denied.

Comment: As i said, enable Git as deployment option. clone the repo, delete the stuff commit and push.

Comment: "You appear to have cloned an empty repository."
but it's not empty, I can se the node_modules folder using FTP!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue today and resolved it by deleting the following App settings from Azure; WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE (Both settings do the same thing, just different names).

This was following instructions in [Vikas Guptas blog on 17 Aug](https://azureappservices.blogspot.com/).

Not sure if you are using VSTS (Azure devops) but it may be helpful to some people to know that using version 4 of Azure App Service Deploy automatically sets the Website_Run_From_Package flag.

Comment: I just changed setting value of WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE from 1 to 0, and it allows me to delete. I have reversed settings once I complete cleanup.